# split one row to multiple record in redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have following table,

```
     _________________
    |id key1 key2 key3|
    ------------------
     1  101  102  103
     2  201  202  203
```

I need a query which will create the following output,

```
    |id key|
    --------
     1  101  
     1  102
     1  103
     2  201
     2  202
     2  203
```

Is there anything other than union all? When I used "union all", i came across an error disk utilization full... I have billions of records.

Comment: Why would you want alternative for the most natural thing to do here?

Comment: As to "Is there anything other than union all" - yes. You should normalize this table to avoid the repeated 'key' columns. This is in fact a textbook example of *why* tables should be normalized.

Comment: Hang on... Which database are you using? You have tagged Oracle, PostgreSQL and Redshift.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select a.id, case b.l when 1 then a.key1 when 2 then a.key2 else a.key3 end key
from mytable a
cross join (select level l from dual connect by level < 4) b
order by 1,2
```

Comment: Can you please explain the statement "select level l from dual connect by level < 4"

Comment: It is to generate numbers here is from 1 to 3. If you want to generate from 1 to 20 for sample, change 4 with 21

Comment: @Mottor...I would like to know the memory utilization of cross join....when I used "union all"  instead of cross join I got disk full error...I have billions of records...which has more memory utilization union all or cross join?

Comment: You should test it. In Oracle there is Explain Plan which can show the predicted memory consumption. I don't know the Redshift. Union all makes separate queries. If you do not sort in memory, the cross join should be better

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is tagged Oracle, you could do:

```
SELECT id, key
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS ( key FOR key_name IN ( key1, key2, key3 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

`union all` is very efficient on Redshift. Doubt there's anything much better.

```
create table new_table as
select id, key1 as key from old_table
union all
select id, key2 as key from old_table
union all
select id, key3 as key from old_table
```

If you want to try something like Mottor suggests you can replace the Oracle specific `dual connect by level` bit with a Redshift hack like so:

```
(select row_number() over (order by true) as l from stv_blocklist limit 3) b
```

The `stv_blocklist` table reference there could be any table with at least 3 rows.